# Failing to pass data between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I don't know why, but this **NOT** work and I think that it should.
Pass data in mainAcitivity:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MapActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MapActivity.LATITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, latitude);
            intent.putExtra(MapActivity.LONGITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, longitude);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Than get data in second activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        mLat = intent.getLongExtra(LATITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, mLat);
        mLong = intent.getLongExtra(LONGITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, mLong);
    }
}
```

What am I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I am dumb and blind :( passing **double** and reading **long**.
putExtra has hidden this type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `v.getContext()` with `YourActivity.this` or with the method `getApplicationContext()`. If you are using a fragment, please use `getActivity()` method. And in your `onClick` method please use `startActivity(intent);` instead of `v.getContext().startActivity(intent);`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: even no need to do that, simply `startActivity(intent)` would work fine.

Comment: @Alex Thx for fast response, I have already found what my issue caused.
v.getContext is fine since it is in onClick where **v** is clicked view.

Comment: Was the issue caused by one of the problems mentioned above?

Comment: @AlexM. Nope, See my answer below. (Can't accept in two days)

Comment: Hmm, but in your post you did not mentioned that `mLat` and `mLong` were declared as `long` instead of `double` :|

Comment: Yes, If I did, maybe I wouldn't post this :(

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your code for several seconds, i finally  found the problem. You're trying to use constants ( `MapActivity.LONGITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, MapActivity.LATITUDE_EXTRA_KEY`) in an activity you've not created in an already created activity. Here is the solution, move all your constants to the first activity, and change the code in your `onClick` method to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MapActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(LATITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, latitude);
            intent.putExtra(LONGITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, longitude);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

And your MapActivity to this onCreate() method to this:

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        mLat = intent.getDoubleExtra(FirstActivity.LATITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, mLat);
        mLong = intent.getDoubleExtra(FirstActivity.LONGITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, mLong);
```

the first activity is the activity that is hosting both the button and your constants. Hope it help

Comment: Nope, **psfs**.

Comment: Okay, what does this psfs mean?

Comment: **public static final String**

try to write it in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are passing `double` values from `MainActivity` and trying to get `long` values from `Intent` in `MapActivity` and this may be causing problem.

**Update your `MapActivity`, `onCreate()` method as below:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        mLat = intent.getDoubleExtra(LATITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, 0.0f);
        mLong = intent.getDoubleExtra(LONGITUDE_EXTRA_KEY, 0.0f);
    }
}
```